# Troubles with .resx files C#

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

Recently, I decided to update my program and decided to add the ability to change the language to it. For this, I created .resx files and filled in with data. When trying to compile I got some error related to "AL.exe". After installing the Windows SDK, the error was fixed. Unfortunately, now there was another error when trying to compile:

```
The task "GenerateResource" has failed unexpectedly.
System.NotSupportedException: The format of the given path is not supported.
   w System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   w System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   w System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
   w System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
   w Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SdkToolsPathUtility.FileExists(String filePath)
   w Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SdkToolsPathUtility.GeneratePathToTool(FileExists fileExists, String currentArchitecture, String sdkToolsPath, String toolName, TaskLoggingHelper log, Boolean logErrorsAndWarnings)
   w Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.ComputePathToResGen()
   w Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   w Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   w Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() (MSB4018)
```

Compilation is successful only if I remove all .resx files from the project. Not only those created by me, but also those generated automatically from UI.

I tried to rebuild the project, clean the project, deleted the bin and obj folders.

There isn't any ":" sign anywhere in the filenames.

[image: Files]

Deleting dots from filenames also doesn't help :/

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Can you unload the project file, then open it in the editor and copy the entries for the resx files as is and paste then here in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem! My problem was the path of the `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory` environment variable.

The value of my environment variable was `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools`, but the correct value is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools`.

The `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory` environment variable should be added as user variable instead of system variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation in *[Work with .resx files programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically)* may help:

> Convert .resx files to binary .resources files Converting .resx files
> to embedded binary resource (.resources) files has significant
> advantages. Although .resx files are easy to read and maintain during
> application development, they are rarely included with finished
> applications. If they are distributed with an application, they exist
> as separate files apart from the application executable and its
> accompanying libraries. In contrast, .resources files are embedded in
> the application executable or its accompanying assemblies. In
> addition, for localized applications, relying on .resx files at run
> time places the responsibility for handling resource fallback on the
> developer. In contrast, if a set of satellite assemblies that contain
> embedded .resources files has been created, the common language
> runtime handles the resource fallback process.
>
> To convert a .resx file to a .resources file, you use Resource File
> Generator (resgen.exe),

resgen.exe is described here:

*[Resgen.exe (Resource File Generator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator)*

Comment: With CMD, I can convert .resx files to .resources. So why does the program have a problem with that?

Comment: Can you [be](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73840827/edit) more specific in your answer? What in particular in the wall of text of quoted text addresses the question? (But ******* ***without*** ******* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the IDE/compiler is complaining because your satellite resource files don't have a main resource file. Try to create a "resource.resx" file in the Resources folder.

Comment: It did not help :/